# how can i consume a method from a connected service in .NET WCF and expose it 'AS IS' in a new method in my WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy, wsdl

My interface look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    myConnectedService.SomeComplexResponseType someMethod(myConnectedService.SomeComplexRequestType request);
}
```

My implementation look like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    myConnectedService_client client = new myConnectedService_client();

    public myConnectedService.SomeComplexResponseType someMethod(myConnectedService.SomeComplexRequestType request)
    {
        myConnectedService.SomeComplexResponseType response = client.connectedServiceMethod(request);

        return response ;
    }
}
```

The error i get when i am trying to run my service:

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

and

> error CS0644: 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'

Comment: Have you enabled metadata in the configuration file? Can you provide some configuration information if you can?

Comment: I have tried to enabled metadata in the configuration file, but with no success..

my configuration file look like this :

Comment: <client>
      <endpoint
        address="http://--------:8088/mockIdentityManagement_v7HttpBinding"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="IdentityManagement_v7HttpBinding"
        contract="IdentityManagement.IdentityManagement_v7"
        name="IdentityManagement_v7HttpBindingPort"
       />
    </client>

Comment: Your configuration file is for the client, and the client cannot enable metadata.

Comment: It is only a little part of the configuration file that i thought is relevant to the connected service i added to my WCF.


Anyway, there is another way to expose metadata from a connected service??
I really need it...

Comment: Do you want to create a WCF service that is the same as the referenced WCF service?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want

Comment: You can’t do this, because the client has only the server interface and no implementation class.

Comment: If you want to run the above code, you must ensure that the server is running, because its essence is still calling the WCF service.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Ding Peng